# Retrofit with Immutables throws runtime exception, when server returns error

Tags: java, json, immutability, retrofit2

If the response is successful everything is working, but when I am getting an 101 error from the server, a runtime exception is thrown: "Failed to invoke public ... TestResponse() with no args", the problem is obviously that json can not be deserialized, but how can I use an error object instead of the "TestResponse" when the I get the error response?

Retrofit interface:

```
@Headers("Accept: application/json")
@POST("api")
Observable<TestResponse> test();
```

Response object:

```
@Value.Immutable()
@Gson.TypeAdapters
public abstract class TestResponse {
    public abstract String success();
}
```

Response successful json:

```
{"success" : "response successful"}
```

Response Error json:

```
[{"error":{"type":101,"description":"not authorized"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to extend the retrofit Callback Class and write your custom Callback for error handling. In your custom Callback class you can deserialize the errorBody into any object type you want. This [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling) has a nice explanation on how to do error handling using that.